# Form for search pages by meta datas

Tags: search, forms, meta-query

Hello I need a form in one wordpress page where an user can search pages by specific meta data.

I found how to do search:
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html#query_meta_values

But how should I create form which then call the query with arguments? After that it then should display the search result.

Currently I have this Form on my page:

`<form action="../process.php" method="post" name="myForm">
  <p>Name <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
  </p>
  <p>eMail <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

Unfortunatelly I still didn't found solution. It would be great if you could help me.

Thanx
Floh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much. In the meanwhile I found out how to solve. My current code is as following:

```
class CustomSearch
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
    add_shortcode('custom_search', array($this, 'shortcode_handler'));
  }

  public function init()
  {
    if (!empty($_POST['nonce_custom_form']))
    {
      if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce_custom_form'], 'handle_custom_form'))
      {
        die('You are not authorized to perform this action.');
      } else
      {
        $error = null;
        if (empty($_POST['workingLanguage']) && empty($_POST['workingArea']) )
        {
          $error = new WP_Error('empty_error', __('Please enter search request.', 'floh'));
          wp_die($error->get_error_message(), __('CustomSearch Error', 'floh'));
        }
        else
        {
          $rd_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'meta_query' => array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
              array(
                'key' => 'name',
                'value' => $_POST['name'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              ),
              array(
                'key' => 'email',
                'value' => $_POST['email'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              )
            )
          );
          $rd_query = new WP_Query( $rd_args );

          $posts = $rd_query->posts;

          // The Loop
          if( $rd_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $rd_query->have_posts() ) {
              $rd_query->the_post();
              echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
          } else {
            // no posts found
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function shortcode_handler($atts)
  {
    return "<form method='post' action=''>
      <p>Name: <input name='name' type='text' value='' /></p>
      <p>eMail: <input name='email' type='text' value='' /></p>
      " . wp_nonce_field('handle_custom_form', 'nonce_custom_form') . "
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
      </form>";
  }

}

$CustomSearch = new CustomSearch();
```

Now I have to find out how to append list to searchpage *below* the form. Or even better, how can I "send" the result $rd_result to default Search-Page?

UPDATE: I learned to use return instead of echo so the output is in proper order. (I dunno why I started using echo)

Best regards
Floh

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/

On your result page, receive the query as follows

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $_POST['name'] ) . '%';
    $email = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $_POST['email'] ) . '%';

    global $wpdb;

    $prepare = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta AS M WHERE M.meta_value LIKE '%s' OR M.meta_value LIKE '%s' ", $name, $email ) );
    $post_ids = array_unique($prepare);

    $search = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',// or your post type
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'post_status' => array('publish','private','future'),//or only 'publish'
        'nopaging' => true,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'cache_results' => false,
    );

    $result = new WP_Query($search);

    if($result->found_posts >= 1){
        while($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post();
            global $post;
            //$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);//If necessary
            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true).', ';
            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true).'<hr>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }else{
        echo 'Nothing here';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Error: Fill the name or email';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution for my requirement. I kept the PHP I just posted but added a id to ul-Element. Then I added an html element and Javascript code in same page where PHP-Code is applied. The HTML part I added is as following:

```
<div id="formattedresult" />
<script>
  var result = document.getElementById('customresult');
  document.getElementById('formattedresult').appendChild(result);
</script>
```

Now I have to make result nice and I'll order a Wordpress-Book! Sorry for posting this topic.

I know there are better solutions, but I have to learn more about Wordpress with PHP.

Best regards!
Floh